# Half of the imageview inside a layout

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, user-interface

```
 _________________
|      test       |
|      ______     |
|_____|      |____|
      |______|
```

This is what i want... The larger box is made with a drawable and inside it has an edittext. The smaller box should be a an imageview with an icon of upload.

When there is nothing in the edittext the imageview will be GONE(Not visible)

```
 _________________
|                 |
|_________________|
```

so when the icon is visible i need to increase the width of the bigger box.The biggerbox has a stroke also.

So far i made it like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingStart="27dp"
        android:paddingEnd="27dp"
        android:paddingBottom="10dp"
        android:paddingTop="10dp"
        android:alpha=".5"
        android:background="@drawable/commenting_drawable">
        <EditText
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="say something"
            android:id="@+id/comments_editText"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textColorHint="@color/white_75"
            android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
            android:textSize="13sp"
            android:textCursorDrawable="@null"
            android:background="@color/transparent"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"/>
    </RelativeLayout>
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginTop="35dp">
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="40dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:background="@drawable/icn_uploadcomment"
            android:src="@drawable/black_circle_25"/>
    </RelativeLayout>
</FrameLayout>
```

this is my drawable

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <solid
        android:color="#ff7c00" />
    <stroke
        android:width="1dp"
        android:color="@color/white"/>
    <corners
        android:topLeftRadius="5dp"
        android:topRightRadius="5dp"
        android:bottomLeftRadius="5dp"
        android:bottomRightRadius="5dp"/>
</shape>
```

So basically i want half of the imagewiew to be inside the biggerbox and i want to make the bigger box adjust itself when image view becomes visible.

Comment: use framelayout

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to find a solution to the above question by providing -ve margin to the smaller box in the xml

```
    <EditText
    android:id="@+id/comment_text"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    style="@style/text_comment_style"
    android:paddingBottom="32dp" />
    <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/comment_recorder_button"
    android:layout_width="@dimen/progress_comment_recorder_diameter"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/progress_comment_recorder_diameter"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="-20dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/comment_text"/>
```

Comment: Can you add anything to why or how this fixed your problem, rather than just showing code? This allows others to learn from your answer and apply it to a broader range of similar questions.

Answer (score 1):

You can reduce the size of the top margin of the relative layout of the image to make it overlap. Since you probably already have code to manipulate the layout since you are making the image view visible and invisible, the easiest way (IMO) to change the size of the bigger box would be to adjust the padding as follows:

```
    RelativeLayout layout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.biggerBox);
    layout.setPadding(left, top, right, bottom);
```

`left, top, right, bottom` would be the padding needed to change the size of the bigger box. (You would also need to give an ID to the bigger box.)

Comment: I was able to make the above layout with -ve margin. I will post the answer.